# SCIM2 not found in WSO2is

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I use WSO2is 5.9, and I have enabled scim tool in deployment.toml as follows:

```
[user_store]:
     scim_enabled=true
```

I try to create a user using this command:

```sh
curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data '{"schemas":[],"name":{"familyName":"jackson","givenName":"kim"},"userName":"kim@KM.COM","password":"kimwso2","emails":[{"primary":true,"value":"kim.jackson@gmail.com","type":"home"},{"value":"kim_j@wso2.com","type":"work"}]}' --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://myidentity.com/scim2/Users
```

part of my output:

```sh
* upload completely sent off: 224 out of 224 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 401
```

If I make a request to scim2 via GET, I get the message:

```
No service was found.
```

Another error using curl is:

```sh
{"schemas":["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"],"detail":"Can not obtain carbon realm service..","status":"500"}* Closing connection 0
```

in WSO2 log i have:

```sh
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim2.provider.resources.AbstractResource} - Server error while handling the request. org.wso2.charon3.core.exceptions.CharonException
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim2.common.impl.IdentitySCIMManager.getUserManager(IdentitySCIMManager.java:124)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim2.provider.resources.GroupResource.processRequest(GroupResource.java:439)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim2.provider.resources.GroupResource.getGroup(GroupResource.java:305)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:225)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:92)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:93)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:146)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:116)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The URL `https://myidentity.com/scim/Users` works to create users, but I can't add custom claims to new users.

Comment: Can you confirm the authorization credentials are correct "admin:admin"?

Comment: Yes, credentials are ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using https://myidentity.com/scim2/Users  endpoint, we presume that you are trying to create user in **super tenant**.

Since you are using email as username, the admin username should also be an emailusername. Use the following command if you are trying to create a user in super tenant.

```
 curl -v -k --user admin@gmail.com:admin --data '{"schemas":[],"name":{"familyName":"jackson","givenName":"kim"},"userName":"kim.jackson@gmail.com","password":"kimwso2","emails":[{"primary":true,"value":"kim.jackson@gmail.com","type":"home"},{"value":"kim_j@wso2.com","type":"work"}]}'
--header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users
```

You got the 401 unautheorised error as you are not using emailusername for super admin user.

If you are trying to create a user in a **tenant**, the admin username should be emailusername appended with respective tenant. And the scim endpoint also should be tenant specific.

An example is given when the tenant is **abc.com**:

```
curl -v -k --user admin@gmail.com@abc.com:admin --data '{"schemas":[],"name":{"familyName":"jackson","givenName":"kim"},"userName":"kim@gmail.com","password":"kimwso2","emails":[{"primary":true,"value":"kim.jackson@gmail.com","type":"home"},{"value":"kim_j@wso2.com","type":"work"}]}'
--header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/t/abc.com/scim2/Users
```

You can refer to the scim api documentation for further reference: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/develop/using-the-scim-2.0-rest-apis/

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have used the username as "kim@KM.COM" which contains '@' character and the Identity Server interprets this as an email address. If you have a requirement to use an email address as a username you need to enable email address as the user name in Identity Server. Please refer [1] to configure it and use above curl command with kim@KM.COM as the user name to create the user. If you don't need to use an email address as a user name please try following curl command.

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data '{"schemas":[],"name":{"familyName":"jackson","givenName":"kim"},"userName":"kim","password":"kimwso2","emails":[{"primary":true,"value":"kim.jackson@gmail.com","type":"home"},{"value":"kim_j@wso2.com","type":"work"}]}' --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users
```

[1] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/using-email-address-as-the-username/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes i use email as username, in my deployment.toml i have this config:
[user_store]
type = "database"
scim_enabled="true"
user_name_attribute="mail"
username_javascript_regex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$"
username_java_regex="^[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}"